# Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int' to return type 'Property<Int>

Tags: swift, xcode, mvvm

I'm trying to implement the MVVM pattern using [Bond](https://github.com/DeclarativeHub/Bond) in a test project.

The idea is simple:

1. Define an abstraction which the viewModel then uses.
2. Make a concrete type from this abstraction.
3. Inject this concrete type in the viewModel.

This is my code so far:

```
// 1.
protocol Commentable {
    var id: Int { get }
    var name: String { get }
    var body: String { get }
}

// 2.
struct Comment: Commentable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var body: String
}

// 3.
struct CommentViewModel {

    private let comment: Commentable

    init(comment: Commentable) {
        self.comment = comment
    }

    public var id: Observable<Int> {
        return self.comment.id
    }
}
```

Xcode shows the following error when I try to `return self.comment.id`:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int' to return type
>   'Property

This makes sense - `comment.id` is an `Int` and `self.id` is an `Observable<Int>`. How do make this work though, since I don't want to define the properties in my `Comment` type as `Observable`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - just had to change the syntax:

```
struct CommentViewModel {

    private let comment: Observable<Commentable>

    init(comment: Commentable) {
        self.comment = Observable(comment)
    }

    public var id: Observable<Int> {
        return Observable(comment.value.id)
    }
}
```